# Return the range within an array Excel

Tags: arrays, excel, indexing, excel-formula, range

I need to retrieve a range delimited by indexes from a specific array

I cannot use OFFSET because it doesnt use an array as a parameter.
And the range will then be use for a secondary calculation

The example:

[image: example data]

I want to calculate the SUM of the 4th to the 11th value in the column Numbers.

So at the end the formula should look something like:
`=SUM(Numbers[4:10]) = 36`  4 and 10 being the desired indexes.

I tried with OFFSET and INDEX but cant figure out how to do it.

Comment: `=SUM(INDEX(B:B,5):INDEX(B:B,11))`?

Comment: @BigBen Yes i tried that, the matter is that the array i am using is not displayed in cells because is a FILTER() from the array NUMBERS  
it is an array that does not contain 0s
=SUM(INDEX(FILTER(Numbers,Numbers<>0),5):INDEX(FILTER(Numbers,Numbers<>0),10)) = #VALUE!

Comment: @Allanguzmanf If OP has `FILTER()` then could use `=SUM(FILTER(B2:B21,(A2:A21>=StartIndex)*(A2:A21<=EndIndex)))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use INDEX and SEQUENCE:

```
=SUM(INDEX(FILTER(Numbers,Numbers<>0),SEQUENCE(8)+3))
```

Answer (score 1):

`Index()`, `INDIRECT()` will work. Also `OFFSET()` will work but need to apply some trick. As @BigBen suggested you can use `INDEX()` like `=SUM(INDEX(B:B,5):INDEX(B:B,11))` but I am sure you will not prefer to hard code index no. So, you can use below formula to dynamically input two index and get sum between those index. Try-

```
=SUM(INDEX(B:B, MATCH(F2,A1:A21,0)):INDEX(B:B,MATCH(F3,A1:A21,0)))
```

Also `INDIREC()` will work in this way.

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("B" & MATCH(F2,A1:A21,0) & ":B" & MATCH(F3,A1:A21,0)))
```

If you have `Excel365` then you can simplify formula using `FILTER()` like-

```
=SUM(FILTER(B2:B21,(A2:A21>=F2)*(A2:A21<=F3)))
```

[image]